# How to change xlabel of figure in every loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

The code below plots a figure in evey loop and I want the average of each matrix printed as a x label. For example: `ave is 40`. I am not sure how to add ave of each image to xlabel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
a= np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, 600, 600))

for i in range(np.size(a,0)):
    b=a[i,:,:]

    ave=np.average(b)
   
    plt.figure()
    sns.heatmap(b, cmap='jet', square=True, xticklabels=False,
                yticklabels=False)
    plt.text(200,-20, "Relative Error", fontsize = 15, color='Black')
    plt.xlabel("ave is...")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: hmmm ```plt.xlabel("ave is..."+str(ave))``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
a= np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, 600, 600))

for i in range(np.size(a,0)):
    b=a[i,:,:]

    ave=np.average(b)
   
    plt.figure()
    sns.heatmap(b, cmap='jet', square=True, xticklabels=False,
                yticklabels=False)
    plt.text(200,-20, "Relative Error", fontsize = 15, color='Black')
    plt.xlabel("ave is {}".format(round(ave, 3)))
    plt.show()
```

To put a numerical value into a string, you can say `'{}'.format(value)`.
This can be done in numerous places using multiple {} brackets - where each bracket must be accompanied by its corresponding value in `format()`.

More information can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

To round off a value, you simply use `round()`, which takes two arguments: the value you would like to round off (in this case the average), followed by the number of decimals. Eg: `round(ave, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks. can you please let me know how I can round the average to 3 decimals?

Comment: As the other answer states, you can also make use of **f-strings**. But this comes down to preference. For this application you could also use string concatenation and the performance wouldn't matter. However, ```format()``` and f-strings are largely considered the best route to take.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use F-string formatting:

```
plt.xlabel(f'ave is {ave}')
```

Note that to avoid numbers with many decimals, you can use

```
ave_round=np.round(ave, 3) # Round to 3 decimals
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
a= np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, 600, 600))

for i in range(np.size(a,0)):
    b=a[i,:,:]

    ave=np.average(b)
    ave_round=np.round(ave, 3) # Round to 3 decimals
   
    plt.figure()
    sns.heatmap(b, cmap='jet', square=True, xticklabels=False,
                yticklabels=False)
    plt.text(200,-20, "Relative Error", fontsize = 15, color='Black')
    plt.xlabel(f"ave is {ave_round}")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: since my average values are less than 1, like 0.0003764. This approach is not working for rounding